# How do I get the id of a mentioned user? discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py, bots

I'm trying to get the id of a mentioned user. So like if somebody sends command and then `@member`
for example `$spy @member`. I need the id of that mentioned user.

I have tried a couple of things like:

```
if '$spy' in message.content:
            if (message.mentions.__len__()>0):
                for user in message.mentions:
                    return await message.channel.send(f"{user}")
```

But this just sends the `@member` name and #number.
What should I do?

Comment: maybe try f"user.id"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve the id of a user by using `user.id`
In your case that would be

```
if '$spy' in message.content:
    if (message.mentions.__len__()>0):
        for user in message.mentions:
            user_id = user.id
            return await message.channel.send(f"{user}")
```